# Need to identify idle kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 spark-streaming consumers with same group id subscribed to a Kafka topic which has only one partition. So that one partition is assigned to one consumer and other consumers are idle. We need to kill the idle consumers. We are using Spark with YARN.

How to identify the consumer which is idle

Is there any commands from kafka to check which consumer is idle or is there any other we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-consumer-groups --group name` will show all clients within a group and those assigned a partition

Although, it doesn't hurt to have backup processes incase one of the consumer threads fails

Comment: Also I want to list the idle ones also. This command will show only the consumers which are assigned partitions

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

$ kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group group_name --members